# Defining functions inside class

Tags: python

I am trying to write two functions inside a class and call them from outside as shown below. Is this a correct way of calling functions?

```
class blah:

  def func1(x1, y1):
  return z1

  def func2(x2, y2):
  return z2

model = blah()
df1 = model.func1(1,2)
df2 = model.func1(df1,4)
```

Comment: Yes this is precisely how you call a function

Comment: No, this is not correct. You are calling instance methods without accounting for the implicit argument `model` being passed to each.

Comment: You need to add an additional parameter to the methods (conventionally named `self`), or you need to define the methods as static (using the `staticmethod` decorator) so that `model` isn't passed as an argument.

Comment: Please see the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: @chepner Just wondering what do you think about the accepted answer? Do you think it is okay? Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add self in the functions inside a class

```
class blah:

    def func1(self, x1, y1):
        z1 = # Your operations
        return z1

    def func2(self, x2, y2):
        z2 = # You operations
        return z2

model = blah()
df1 = model.func1(1,2)
df2 = model.func1(df1,4)
```

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func1'`

Comment: @ferrelwill Why is `model` bound to a function? What does you code actually look like?

Comment: @Ankit thank you. When do you use `def __init__(self)` then? Assigning this inside a class is a better way of writing the code?

Comment: def __init__(self) is your constructor in python [Python Constructor](https://pythonbasics.org/constructor/)